# Google Tag Manager Link Click returns boolean value "false"

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I have set up a "linkClick" trigger to track menu clicks. But it shows false instead of the actual text in the Click Text variable. How is it even possible for a string parameter to return a boolean?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem as you, when setting up a auto-event variable and custom javascript, where return type would always be boolean and result false.

Asking around, there seems to be a problem with Google Tag Manager at the moment, so you are just encountering a bug.

Keep an eye on Google Tag Manager the coming days as it should hopefully be worked out!